# How to specify multiple sys_platforms with Pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, pipfile

I'm trying to use `Pipenv` to specify a particular package to only install on Linux or Mac.
According to [pep496](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/#id7), I should be able to do something like this in a requirements file.

```
unicon; sys_platform == 'linux' or sys_platform  == 'darwin'
```

This is what the equivalent `Pipfile` section looks like.

```
[packages]
requests = "*"
unicon = {version = "*", sys_platform = "== 'linux' or == 'darwin'"}
```

This creates a `Pipfile.lock` without error but also without any marker information.
When installing from windows it should just skip trying to install `unicorn` but it doesn't and there isn't a version of unicorn for windows so I get an install error.

I realize I could probably make things easy and just do `sys_platform = "!= 'win32'"` but I was wanting to be explicit about the platforms.

Is there any kind of `in ['linux', 'darwin']` way to do this?

Comment: still wondering if there is a solution to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `markers` instead of `sys_platform`, the syntax from your PEP 496 example can be used to specify multiple platforms in `Pipfile`:

```
[packages]
unicon = {version = "*", markers = "sys_platform == 'linux' or sys_platform == 'darwin'"}
```

Comment: How do you specify for Apple ARM chips?

Comment: @user [All PEP 508 environment markers are supported](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile#pep-508-support), so you should be able to specify it as `platform_machine = "== 'arm64'"`, maybe in combination with some Apple-specific marker.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to **not** install **pypiwin32** on Linux.  I had to specify another dependency not listed in my requirements.txt: **pywin32**

Additionally, I used the **os_name** marker :

```
pypiwin32 = { version = "==223",  os_name = "=='nt'"}
pywin32 = {version = "*",   os_name = "=='nt'"}
```

And the two packages need the `markers` in Pipfile:

```
 "markers": "os_name == 'nt'",
```

The installation using pipenv now works.